# How to get the value counts of the specified column?

Tags: python, pandas

```
rev_id  worker_id   label
37675   1362    1.0 
37675   2408    0.0 
37675   1493    0.0 
37675   1439    1.0 
37675   170     0.0 
37675   176     0.0 
37675   481     1.0 
37675   487     0.0 
37675   578     0.0
```

Here is the paragraph of the data frame, I want to group by the rev_id and the value counts of `label`, label only has two values: 1 & 0. New data frame should have two new columns which is the count of label=1 and label=0 for every rev_id.
How to realize it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) and last reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.groupby('rev_id')['label'].value_counts().unstack()
```

Or `groupby` by both columns and use [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['rev_id', 'label']).size().unstack()

print (df)
label   0.0  1.0
rev_id          
37675     6    3
```

Comment: Thanks. How to rename the columns: 0 1

Comment: You can add `.rename(columns={0:'zero', 1:'one'})`

Comment: if `0` and `1` are strings, `.rename(columns={'0':'zero', '1':'one'})`